# Wrapping a ListView inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a screen with a `TextView` at the top, the `ListView` in the middle and a `Button` at the bottom. I'd like it to be so that the `TextView` always is the top at the screen and the button always is the bottom, and then the `ListView` is in between. When the `ListView` exceeds the "space in the middle" I'd like the scroll-function to be only between the `TextView` and `Button`. With my attempt it just expands beyond the `TextView` and `Button`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/paper" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLOL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Standardvarer"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvLOL"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNyVare"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNyVare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Tilføj ny vare"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this helps(the `LinearLayout` wrapping the `ListView` should be removed(and move the layout_above/below to the `ListView`) if you only use it to wrap the `ListView` and nothing else):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/paper" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLOL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Standardvarer"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNyVare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Tilføj ny vare"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvLOL"
    android:layout_above="@id/bNyVare"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's important to put the LinearLayout with the ListView at the bottom of your xml-definition because you have to define the TextView and Button first in order to use their id's in layout_below/above. And i would consider deleting the LinearLayout completely

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative solution to that of @Luksprog, although that's definitely the way to go for more complex layouts. I would ditch the `LinearLayout` that surrounds the `ListView` though, as it doesn't add anything, except for unnecessary complexity in the view hierarchy.

A relatively simple layout as described in your question can also be written using a `LinearLayout` as root and a weight on the `ListView` to dynamically fill up all space inbetween the `TextView` and `Button`. This weight also pushes the `Button` all the way to the bottom, without pushing it off.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/paper" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLOL" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Standardvarer" android:textSize="40dp" />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bNyVare" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Tilføj ny vare"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```