# ListView inside LinearLayout breaking out (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

Been struggling with this for a while now. I have a layout XML consisting of various LinearLayouts, with separate weighting. The end result looks like this..

[image: Image of Main activity screen]

Dont mind the colors, its just to see the break points..Anyway, below the Terminal/Origin etc LinearLayout is a ListView which is populated using a custom adapter. The data loads fine, but then the listView "breaks out" of the LinearLayout, and takes up most of the page

[image]

(Dont mind the colors, its just to see the break points..)

ie. it flows over the View above and below.

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="getFlightInfo"
        android:text="Refresh" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_cell1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@string/cell_1_weight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/table_header_terminal"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_cell2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@string/cell_2_weight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/table_header_origin"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_cell3"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@string/cell_3_weight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/table_header_flight"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_cell4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@string/cell_4_weight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/table_header_scheduled"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_cell5"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@string/cell_5_weight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/table_header_status"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00FF00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I may be missing something glaring, but for the life of me, I cant see it. Can anyone help?

Thanks a million..

Comment: Don't put your `ListView` into a `LinearLayout` and try setting `android:layout_weight=1` on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have kept LinearLayout's height(the one wrapping listview) "wrap_content".Fixing its size to some dip would solve your problem.

Also make listview's height "fill_parent" then.

**EDIT :**

try this way:

...

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

in upper two layouts,you user 0.2 and 0.4 as weight but in lower two layouts,you users 3 and 1...try it former way and see,if it can help you.also try making height of LinearLayout(the one wrapping listview) to 0dip.

Comment: Thanks. But kind of defeats the purpose of having android:layout_weight then (by fixing the height, that is)..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is late, but I could help someone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Content 1" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Content 2" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#00f0f0"></ListView>
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. after consulting [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873128/wrapping-a-listview-inside-a-linearlayout) I came up with a fix

1. Remove the LinearLayout outside the ListView, its superfluous.
2. Add a height of '0px' (which I've found around the web) to the ListView ensures it obeys the android:weight parameter properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the weight of `id/filter`.
- Let the `ListView` have a weight of 1 with `fill_parent` height.
- Remove the listView's immediate parent.

One other thing you missed, is to set the `weightSum=sum_of all_child_weight` in your root. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Why should they not have weights defined? I want them to be proportional to one another?

Comment: Coz `weight` only works with linearlayout.. and height should be 0 to be effective..

Comment: Sorry, I had that done previously, and removed it temporarily. But it didnt help, no.